# Normal capacitor vs. audio capacitor

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, audio, microphone, condenser-microphone

I'm building a power supply for old [Schoeps CMT30F](https://web.archive.org/web/20170713032325/http://www.schoepsclassics.de/1965_cmmt30.htm) microphones. Standard condenser mic are 48V-powered nowadays, but these are 60s/70s Schoeps mic from RadioFrance/ORTF, customized at that time to be -9V or -10V powered.

I need to add capacitors to avoid the 9V to go in the preamp / audio interface.

I was told to buy "audio capacitors polarized 100 µF, 50V, preferably Vishay" (formerly Philips?). These are more than [3€ per unit](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/VISHAY-BC-COMPOSANTS-MAL214631101E3-CONDENSATEUR-RADIAL-50V-100UF/182356045024?hash=item2a75446ce0:g:pesAAOxyeR9TIjEm), and these Vishay are [11.89€](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/condensateurs-aluminium/8506345/) per unit!

**Question: what kind of difference is there between such a capacitor, for audio applications, and a [bog-standard 100 µF / 50V](https://www.gotronic.fr/art-condensateur-radial-100uf-50v-229.htm), that costs 0.20€, i.e. 15 times less/60 times less?**

Will the difference be hearable in the audio frequency spectrum?

---

By the way, here is the ... hum ... sche ... schematics of the power supply I'm about to build.

[image: schematics]

The capacitors are the 2 things in pink near the audio interface (bottom of the drawing). Do you think it's more or less correct?

Comment: Upvoted. You are right to be very suspicious when something is specific for 'audio'. You might have heard of the $10.000 ethernet cables being sold to audiophiles. If you realise all the data over that is digital you can see it is bonkers.

Comment: I always had the impression, "audio cap" meant "low ESL" in the old days.

Comment: Given the typical price of a Schoeps, why quibble over 3 Euros? That's the famous "halfpenny worth of tar". Yes there is a lot of hype over audio products, but sometimes the right component does matter too. Recognised names like Vishay or Philips are not primarily hypesters.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm totally ok to pay 3€ or even 30€ for a component if there is a real noticeable difference in audio quality at the end. I asked this question because I didn't know if "audio" cap is just a hype word... Electrons don't know if it's audio or not at the end ;)

Comment: Although there aren't "audio" caps per se, the [orientation of the cap can matter for audio equipment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnR_DLd1PDI) due to their construction. And since polarized caps can only safely be oriented one way there could be a mismatch of orientations.

Comment: Going the other way I used an "audio" grade cap to replace the motor start capacitor in my clothes dryer. Works just as well. Not sure if the dryer sounds better though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's forget about audio for now and try to find where the price difference lies in the specific products you mentioned, first.

- Main reason: the ebay seller of the Vishay cap seems to mistake his customers for cash cows. The exact same cap on Digikey is less than 1€ (unit price - it doesn't have the same product code: MAL214651101E3, but this is just a packaging difference).
- The cheap cap is specified for 85° (according to the product range in which you found it - because it has no datasheet). The Vishay cap is specified as 2500h to 6000h at 125°C, which is very good, and therefore expensive.
- The cheap cap, as I mentioned, has no datasheet. It means it probably comes from a huge stock of whatever no-name manufacturer (the one which is cheaper at the time the seller needs to reorder from the manufacturer). It doesn't necessarily means it's crap (but don't expect exceptional lifetime/tolerance/ESR/...), but it means its specs could be different from order to order.

Now for the audio part:

The [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28401/146rti.pdf) of the Vishay cap nowhere mentions audio in it. Indeed, What seems to be interesting with this specific product range is the lifetime and ripple current capability. Which makes it ideal for high-power supplies used in industrial environments.

Nothing to do with audio DC blocking.

**Conclusion**: Both parts you linked will probably have the same performance for audio applications. The Vishay will likely last much longer, but audio isn't very demanding anyway.

Now, when looking for excellent performance in audio applications, people tend to prefer film capacitors (e.g. polypropylene) rather than electrolytics because they don't degrade over time. But for 100µF, it will cost an arm and a leg (why 100µF, by the way?? It seems pretty high - 50V seems way above what is really necessary, as well).

Anyway, don't fool yourself too much with "audiophile" stuff. Be pragmatic.

---

**Added later**

Following your edit where you mention another Vishay cap at 11.89€: again, looking at the specs, these are *not* designed specifically for audio (actually, the designers certainly did not have audio in mind *at all*, here, and they would probably laugh their heads off, if they saw it used as such). They are designed, as the datasheet says explicitly, with "high reliability" in mind. I don't really know what that actually translates to, and whether it really justifies a x50 price tag, but then again, this certainly *won't* lead to better audio performances.

You're actually not looking at typical "audiophile" stuff here. And I'm surprised your friend suggested those kind of caps. These are just expensive, industrial-grade capacitors, not targeted for audio applications at all.

So... There we go, I'll bite, and I'll tell you what is the typical "**über-audiophile**" cap that amateurs recommend on forums, and that often lead to opinion wars: the ***Rubycon Black Gate***! Tadaam... Well, they went out of prod about 10 years ago, but if you search on the internet, you can find some 100µ 50V for about 50$.

Be careful, some of them are [fake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDTXp.png).

More seriously, there are reputed manufacturers who currently produce electrolytic caps specifically designed for audio. For example, [the SIMLIC series from ELNA](http://web.archive.org/web/20180522154601/http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/onkyou/index.html). Those sell at a much more reasonable price (typically around 1€ for a 100µ 50V), and if your question was whether *those* kind of capacitors *really specifically designed for audio* (unlike all the examples you suggested) were worth it or not, it would actually be more difficult to give a definitive answer...

My guess is: If you did a real blind test, you most likely wouldn't be able to tell the difference. But sometimes, at a hobby level, there are some psychological factors to account for when designing stuff, and, if you can go to sleep at night with a sweet smile on your face just because you know your signal goes through an "audio-grade" capacitor, it may be totally worth the 0.80€ difference, even if it provides objectively no improvements in sound... Up to you, I won't judge.

For professional audio equipment manufacturers, it is different. I wouldn't trust a designer who would not make the actual measurements and compare the real capacitors performances in situ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why 100 µF? I don't know, I was told to use that ones by someone who did this unit before... Do you think it's a good value?

Comment: By the way @dim, here is the ... hum ... sche ... [schematics](https://gget.it/04x42/SchoepsAlim.jpg) of my power supply I'm about to build. The capacitors are the 2 things in pink near the audio interface (bottom of the drawing). Do you think it's more or less correct?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with XLR stuff and even less with old condenser mics from ORTF (sans déconner? Celui du général de Gaulle?), but it seems correct.

Comment: Haha yes ORTF :)

Comment: Now, 100µF as an audio DC-blocking cap is huge, indeed. The resulting cut-off frequency depends on the impedance of the device it goes to, but even with 1k impendace, it gives 1.6Hz. It doesn't need to be so low. You could use 10µF, or even 1µF if the device has a high enough input impedance. (in which case using a good film cap starts to make sense).

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the CMT30F impedance, but let's say it's medium impedance. What cut-off would create a 10 µF or 1 µF?

Comment: It's not really the impedance of the microphone that counts. It is the impedance of the input it goes to. Basically, the impedance of the amplifier/sound card/whatever you're connecting it to. Anyway, a typical figure is 10kOhm, which would give 1.6Hz with 10µF and 16Hz with 1µF: f=1/(2×pi×R×C)

Comment: Thank you @dim. Funnily, I tested many audio interfaces and my cheap Tascam US122L has a good mic preamp, as good as a RME high-end audio interface I tested (in terms of SNR especially). So I'll use this cheap interface with the expensive Schoeps mics ;) It is said to have [2.4 kOhm impedance](http://tascam.com/content/downloads/products/312/US122L_E_Web.pdf) in the manual. So it seems it will have a cutoff of 0.7 Hz with a 100 µF cap. Is it fine for DC-blocking?

Comment: Well, 0.7Hz means you are well beyond the hearing range, which is perfect for DC blocking. But probably way overkill... Do you think you can hear a 0.7Hz sound? Actually, I'd rather have a cutoff at 7Hz with a 10µ polypropylene cap than a cutoff at 0.7Hz with an electrolytic cap... But I also advised you to be pragmatic, so I'm contradicting my own self here... Whatever floats your boat will be fine.

Comment: I'll also add that while it's easy to say Digikey is much cheaper than "a random reseller", it's not as simple as saying "just get any of the 684 aluminum electrolytic capacitors that are 100µF, 50V, you can't go wrong." Resellers often call the down-selection a "value-added service". Whether or not *you* need this service is another matter.

Comment: @Basj I didn't see your latest edits, actually. I updated my answer with a bit more information regarding "real" audio-grade caps.

Comment: I don’t know why but the correct answer should state how the mic FET is biased with 2.4k to DC then blocked after this using the Balanced XLR input.   Note that ESR and rated temp is irrelevant with this Drain impedance and very low current and thus zero temp rise.  Does everyone understand these old mic’s were vintage FET buffered just like Electret  mic’s and know why/where the DC blocking must be done correctly to bias the mic’s FET yet not saturated the preamp?  How is that all connected? On a balanced XLR interface?

Answer (score 10):

[image: Choice flowchart for 142 RHS]

I was curious, because I have the feeling that a component being "audio" is partly driven by belief, but in so many cases there are underlying reasons for that belief to be sensible. In the most compact form, here is what Vishay supplies on how to choose their caps. I made a small filtering in Digikey, and concluded that a fair comparison would be 142 RHS, it is a decade cheaper.

In such components, even slight deviations from what may be deemed as standard (i.e. its manufacturing is standardized to a point that a company can outsource the production to no-name manufacturers in the far east.) may result in price hikes. E-bay is the differentiator here, though. Here you have it in better price: https://www.digikey.nl/short/jhm8m2

But still the question remains. 142RHS --> 140RTM makes the component industrial grade, and --> 146 RTI lowers its Z, which means that its parasitic resistance, and to some degree inductance will be lower.

146RTI is also AEC-Q100 which means that it is unit tested to some degree for automotive applications.

Audio:
[image: 146RTI]
Not Audio:
[image: 142RHS]
[image: 142RHS Ripple]

These datasheets cram up as much info as needed, thats why it is tiresome to read, but I think the information is here. I would calculate the peak current that you will supply in your power supply, and try to keep the parasitic impedance (or the voltage ripple, when multiplied with the current) within spec of your choice. Also, one must account for the heating caused by the ripple current.

My .02, sorry I wasn't comprehensive enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not expert at all in electronics, so I don't know exactly what to conclude. What would be your conclusion? Choose the 3€ or the 0,20€ one or other ones? (I only need 4 caps, so I need to find a seller where I can do an order of just that!)

Comment: If I had to choose, I would go for the cheaper alternative. I presume here that a microphone is not power hungry as a power amp (might be wrong obv) therefore it might be well of without the low Z.

Answer (score 8):

> Question: what kind of difference is there between such a capacitor, for "audio applications"

First "audio application" doesn't mean anything. A capacitor can serve many different uses, for example power supply decoupling, or signal DC blocking, and what makes a capacitor good at one specific use does not make it good at another use. So you have to be more specific.

There is a lot of mysticism in audio, like "this part is awesome" but they don't tell you what it is awesome at (or why).

Your application seems to be an AC-coupling cap (ie, DC-blocking cap) on a signal line, for a microphone which uses a kind of "phantom power" from a 9V battery.

In this case:

- Current through the cap will be very low, so it doesn't need to be low-ESR. Some resistance in series, even tens of ohms, won't make any difference. So we can ignore ESR.
- Temperature will be "ambient" so it doesn't need to be a model specified to withstand high temperatures. It wouldn't hurt, but it wouldn't help much either. A quality 85°C cap will last decades at ambient temp.
- In a DC blocking application we want low DC leakage current, so we'll ignore tantalums and polymers, and restrict our choice to quality aluminium and film caps. These have very low leakage, usually. For example polymer caps are optimized for lowest ESR at the expense of cost and leakage.
- There will be a DC voltage across the cap, and it is connected to a high impedance mic input, so it is very important that it isn't microphonic.

We want to avoid a cap whose capacitance varies when it vibrates. Thus, high-K ceramics like X7R are out. This is also kinda correlated to the size of the capacitor, as capacitance depends on the distance between the plates. Large "audiophile" film caps are more microphonic...

This is a bit unscientific, but some time ago I needed a vibration-proof coupling cap, so I grabbed a bunch of caps, put some DC across the cap, and hit them with a pencil. The electrolytics were the least microphonic. Large audiophile film caps are surprisingly microphonic.

- If your cable runs on a stage, maybe you need to put the DC blocking cap on the mic side. If the cable has DC on it, and someone steps on it, the cable capacitance change may be enough to cause an audible thump.

So, between film and electrolytic, in this case I'd use electrolytic due to the smaller size and absence of microphony. You can try Panasonic FM series, but really any good quality cap will work.

It is a good idea to use a higher value than required by a 20Hz cutoff, because electrolytic caps aren't accurate (so your 20Hz cutoff may be way off, like 10-40Hz), plus you don't know the value of the R in the RC network, and they will generate distortion if you use them as filters and allow an AC voltage to develop across the cap.

Well that was a long way to say "use a good quality electrolytic".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me to understand what factors are important. (Note for future reference: Electrolytic = chimique = électrochimique, because we often also see those terms in French)

Comment: As this one has no branding (sourcing might vary): https://www.gotronic.fr/art-condensateur-radial-100uf-50v-229.htm, would you use another one or still use those?

Comment: I would use Panasonic FM because I have some in stock, but that will also work fine. Besides, on your soundcard there will also be a general purpose electrolytic coupling cap on the input...

Comment: Would you have a Farnell or Radiospare reference? Because there are probably dozains of Panasonic FM 100 µF cap references... Thank you in advance.

Comment: I like reichelt as it has low postage to France! [link](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/fr/Electrolyte-Capacitors-105-C-1000-5000h/FM-A-100U-50/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=2&ARTICLE=200028&GROUPID=4000&artnr=FM-A+100U+50&trstct=pol_5) [link](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/fr/Electrolyte-Capacitors-105-C-5000-10000h/RAD-FR-100-50/3/index.html?ACTION=3&LA=2&ARTICLE=121283&GROUPID=5513&artnr=RAD+FR+100%2F50&trstct=pol_9)

Comment: Note you can use pretty much any electrolytic cap... don't go spending $$$ to acquire these LOL, I said the main reason I'd use this series is cause I have some. If you got some general purpose electrolytics of proper voltage it'll also work.

Comment: Note if you only have 9V across the cap you can use a 16V cap, instead of 50V it'll be smaller. It might even fit inside your XLR, so that would be nice.

Comment: Thanks @peufeu! Only 5,60€ postage and no minimum order, that's perfect for sometimes small projects!

Answer (score 4):

I think that the authoritative work on audio is Doug Self's ["Small Signal Audio Design"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780240521770), and in it Doug looks in some detail at things like distortion in capacitors. His observations are not some audiophile nonsense, but backed up by solid research.

He suggests that to avoid having any appreciable signal voltage across electrolytics. If you do so, this is when they can introduce distortion. In this case, the voltages are small - so there should be no issue. (In fact using electrolytics to block +48V volts phantom is very common practice even in high end gear.)

The other way to do this is of course to use a good quality mic transformer - but that will cost you a bit more.

Comment: Does Self say you should avoid DC voltage across caps, or AC voltage? The latter is common knowledge, but if it's the former I'll have to read the book ;)

Comment: Signal voltage - AC. It's worth reading anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

After having tried many different capacitors for the microphone power supply, here are some conclusions of my tests:

- Kemet vs. "noname" 10uF capacitors: similar in terms of SNR, no significant difference in favor of one or another
- Vishay vs. "noname" 100uF capacitors: idem

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401176/how-to-improve-this-microphone-phantom-power-supply-to-have-better-snr/403258#403258) are more details about the tests and the results.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the key parameter may be the leakage current. The insulation layer in an elcap must be formed and maintained by moving ions (?) through the electrolyte. This takes current x time = charge. Until that process has completed there will be a significant leakage current, and the C will self-discharge within a few seconds. Consider that this current may flow through your microphone and may cause distortion.

It is recommended to "form" elcaps by connecting them to a DC source through a current limiting resistor for a day or so. And this has to be repeated after a long time of no use, or else (in the case of an elcap in a power supply): kaboom !

Avoiding them is probably the easier option.